# jquery autocomplete by textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery

let u as consider the value am having in `textbox` so now if we type in that it automatically 
have to show word with multi-value by comma.  I have tried but no result.

Can any body help out of this problem.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function()
            {
               var val = document.getElementById('tags').value;
               var availableTags = val == '' : [] ? val.split(',');

    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#tags" )
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
          // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
          response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          return false;
        }
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
  <input id="tags" size="25" value="ACCENTURE 1,    
BPCL KORAMANGALA,
CUNNIGHAM ROAD,
HM TOWERS,  
GREATER NOIDA,  
INFOSYS 3,  
JAYANAGAR T BLOCK,  
MILLENIA,   
OZONE,  
BKC,    
FUN REPUBLIC,   
MATUNGA,
VFS UK, 
CYBER GREEN,    
PRABHADEVI, 
VRINDAVAN"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check this: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, your **`autocomplete`**(which I have tested in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3gSc/1/)) is not populating.  The reason is you *[ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) syntax is wrong.*

```
 var availableTags = val == '' : [] ? val.split(',');  //WRONG
```

Change this to

```
 var availableTags = val == '' ? [] : val.split(',');  //CORRECT
```

See it is working in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A3gSc/)

Comment: @user2009765 Glad to help you, my friend :)

Comment: @user2009765 You means default alertbox of the browser?

Comment: @user2009765 **No you can't do that with default alert box, because each browser has its own styles.**  However it is possible using *[jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)* and also more *plugins* available.

Comment: am new to jquery can u suggest how to learn easily and quickly...which book is better to learn quickly....with lot example..

Comment: @user2009765 `easily and quickly` possible only by practicing.  jQuery is a library, which gets updated each time(books won't be updated enough better to go with [api docs](http://api.jquery.com/)) so concentrate  `js` and the book I like is *javascript - the good parts* join the club I'm also still a reader of this book and learner :)